# Preprocessing view if grouping is enabled

Tags: views, 9

Views has base template **views-view-unformatted.html.tpl** with contents:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where variable *{{ title }}* - mean The title of this group of rows. It's usually empty.

So, I want to preprocess this template in my .theme file and override this *{{ title }}* variable (or assign new) with my contents for this view if grouping enabled.

[image: Grouping enabled]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What's the question/problem?

Comment: @berliner Question in last paragraph: I want preprocess {{title}} variable in this template. I want change {{title}} contents for each group. I wasn't doing this in template because required do some php actions.